# Resample and select a given number of rows and calculate the mean, variance and confidence intervals?

Tags: r, for-loop, random

I need to select a especific number of rows per resampling from 4 to 50 rows.

So, in the first run I need that the function select 4 random rows and calculate the mean, variance and confidence intervals for a given variable and this has to be done *1000 times*. The second run I need the same thing, but instead of selecting 4 rows I need that selct 5 random rows 1000 times... until 54 rows.

The example:

```
x1 <- matrix(rnorm(200,mean=10), nrow= 100, ncol=2)
x2 <- c(replicate(5, "AA"),replicate(15, "BB"),replicate(15, "CC"),
        replicate(10, "DD"),replicate(10, "EE"),replicate(10, "FF"),
        replicate(10, "GG"),replicate(5, "HH"),replicate(5, "II"),
        replicate(15, "JJ"))
df <- data.frame(cbind(x1,x2))
colnames(df) <- c("variable1", "variable2","group")
```

I'm running these code below, *manually*, and it is seems that is right.

```
samples <- vector(mode="list", length=1000)
for (i in 1:1000){
  samples[[i]]=sample(as.numeric(df$variable1),size=4,replace=F)
}

# funtionc to calculate confidence interval
conf <- function(x) {
  error <- qnorm(0.975)*sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))
  return (data.frame("lower" = mean(x)-error,
                     "upper" = mean(x)+error))
}

# calculating mean, variance and confidence interval of the simulations

mean1 <- lapply(samples,mean) # calculating the mean of these 4 select rows per simulation
mean2 <- unlist(mean1) # unlist the list of the means values
mean_4rows <- mean(mean2) # the total mean of the randomly selected rows

var1 <- lapply(samples,var) # calculating the var of these 4 select rows per simulation
var2 <- unlist(var1)
var_4rows <- mean(var2) # the mean of the total variance of the randomly selected rows

conf1 <- lapply(samples,conf) # calculating the var of these 4 select rows per simulation
conf2 <- unlist(conf1)
conf_4rows <- mean(conf2) # the mean of the total conf interval of the randomly selected rows
```

However, I have to automate this code, to be able to run it so that I can select from 4 to 50 random rows (1000 times each number of rows selection) and calculate the mean, variance and CIs of the simulations.

In the end I would like a object with the total means, variance and CIs for the number of selected rows generated by the simulations,with the rows refering to  the selection of 4 rows, and 5 selected random rows.... etc until 50 rows:

```
#>    rows  meanSim varianceSim  lowerCISim   upperCISim
#>    4     1.84     0.410        0.105       0.300
#>    5     1.69     0.951        1.023       2.098  
#>    6     1.99     0.714        1.234       1.987
#>   ..... 
#>    50    2.58     0.242        2.098       2.999
```

> Any idea on how I can make this automated and save these results?

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify a few things: do you want to simulate this on varibale 1 or 2? When you calculate the mean/var/CI for w.g 4 rows and then do this 1000 times, the output qould have 1000 rows per selected number of rows, so potentially sth. about 50k rows. Do you actually want this or do you want to calculate the mean across these 1000 resamples and store that?

Comment: I‘m also not sure if what you are doing is right. Usually in simulations, you have your metrics (like mean, var…). But what you are actually doing currently is to take the mean of e.g. 4 rows, do this 1000 times, and then get the mean of these 1000 resamples. So far so good. But then you are calculating 1000 vars, but then you are not taking the mean foe these 1000 vars, but you are calculating the variance again. Similar foe the CIs. Is that really what you want?

Comment: @deschen yes. It's only for one variable indeed. Example: select 4 random rows, calculate the mean, variance and CIs. Now that tyou pointed, yes, the correct would be to calculate the mean of variance and confidence intervals in the end. This would be done a 1000 times for 4 rows, and in the end I would like the mean of these 1000 mean values, the mean of these 1000 variance values and the mean of these 1000 CI values. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right what you want to do here‘s a possible pipeline for achieving this. In the num vector you can specify the range of rows.

library(tidyverse)

```
num <- 4:20

df %>%
  map(.x = num,
      .f = ~replicate(1000, df %>%
        slice_sample(n = .x) %>%
        summarize(m = mean(variable1),
                  v = var(variable1),
                  CI_lower = m - qnorm(0.975)*sd(variable1)/sqrt(length(variable1)),
                  CI_upper = m + qnorm(0.975)*sd(variable1)/sqrt(length(variable1)))) %>%
        unlist() %>%
        matrix(nrow = 4) %>%
        t() %>%
        as.data.frame() %>%
        summarize(rows = .x,
                  across(everything(), ~mean(.)))) %>%
      bind_rows() %>%
      rename_with(.cols = -1,
                  .fn = ~c('meanSim', 'varianceSim', 'lowerCISim', 'upperCISim'))
```

Which gives e.g.

```
   rows  meanSim varianceSim lowerCISim upperCISim
1     4 10.13154   1.0577446   9.186789   11.07630
2     5 10.07109   1.0506029   9.222398   10.91978
3     6 10.09189   0.8967657   9.364972   10.81881
4     7 10.03287   0.9818307   9.324943   10.74080
5     8 10.06811   1.0611820   9.371995   10.76423
6     9 10.04530   1.0317911   9.398955   10.69165
7    10 10.01383   0.9215538   9.434336   10.59332
8    11 10.07672   0.9822049   9.503872   10.64956
9    12 10.05113   0.9700539   9.503550   10.59870
10   13 10.05592   0.9979925   9.523299   10.58853
11   14 10.05376   1.0303104   9.530158   10.57736
12   15 10.05985   0.9436392   9.574632   10.54508
13   16 10.03238   1.0234298   9.542458   10.52230
14   17 10.02374   0.9527581   9.563989   10.48350
15   18 10.05378   0.9982555   9.596471   10.51109
16   19 10.04348   1.0059833   9.597250   10.48971
17   20 10.00430   0.9687532   9.577334   10.43126
```

Comment: thank you!! Just one question to confirm: so the `summarize(rows = .x, across(everything(), ~mean(.))))` is calculating the mean of the 1000 simulations for the three results (mean, variance and confidente interval), is that right?

Comment: Yes, I‘m taking e.g. 4 random rows, calculate their mean, var and CIs. I repeat that 1000 times. And then I‘m taking the mean of these 1000 values for each metric (mean, var, CIs).